# Backgroundimage follow Mousecursor

Tags: jquery, css

I want to have effect like this: 
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/interactive_bg_demo.html

The background image should follow the mouse cursor. Is there an easy way to do that without taking the script from the example?

I've already tried something like this:

```
$('#outer').mousemove(function(e){
    var xwidth = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var ywidth = e.pageX - this.offsetRight;
  if (xwidth <= 1200) {
      $('#bg').css({'right': xwidth});           
  }

   if (ywidth >= 500) {
      $('#bg').css({'left': ywidth});           
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that you posted uses CSS Transforms Matrix to change the position of the background layer. The image must be centered so you can't move it by changing the right and left position of the background image.

You should display a layer with absolute position covering your screen with margin but with low z-index to serve as a background. On mouse move shift layer's position with css transform property.

```
var maxMove = 10;
var d = $(window);
var bg = $("#bg");
bg.width(d.width()+maxMove*2).height(d.height()+maxMove*2).css('top','-' + maxMove + 'px').css('left','-' + maxMove + 'px');

$(window).mouseleave(function(){
    //bg.css('transform','matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var xPos = event.pageX;
    var yPos = event.pageY;

    var w = d.width();
    var h = d.height();

    var xShift = ((w/2 - xPos)/w*2)*maxMove;
    var yShift = ((h/2 - yPos)/h*2)*maxMove;

    $("#log").text(xShift);
    bg.css('transform','matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, ' + xShift + ', ' + yShift + ')');

});
```

Of course don't forget the CSS:

```
#bg{
    position:absolute;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1861-1370-1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    z-index:-1;
}
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check out [detailed tutorial](http://avantiveloceblog.com/cool-moving-background-effect/) and live demo.

Read about Css Transforms Matrix [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/)

Answer (score 0):

By just searching the web for what you want to achieve, the very first result led to this page:
http://jsfiddle.net/geekambassador/a6ekn/

```
bg.mousemove(function(event) {
  var xPos = event.pageX;
  TweenLite.to(bg, .5, {css:{backgroundPosition:xPos + "px"}});
});
```

Hope it helps.